# Override JavaScript class prototype inside a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I tried to override the **Text** class prototype function `doSomething`.
The class **Editor** initialises its `txt` with **Text** inside the `_initText` function.

The issue is my override code has never been really taken and overridden the original code.

No errors, when I run `editor.txt.doSomething()` it still print the "old message".

Please help on how to override this type of prototype in JavaScript. Plenty thanks.

> editor.js

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function Text(editor) {
    this.editor = editor;
}

Text.prototype = {
    constructor: Text,

    init: function init() {
        this.doSomething();
    },

    doSomething: function doSomething() {
        console.log('old message');
    },
};

function Editor(editor) {
    this.editor = editor;
}

Editor.prototype = {
    constructor: Editor,

    _initText: function _initText() {
        this.txt = new Text(this);
        this.txt.init();
    },

    init: function init() {
        this._initText();
    }
};
```

> extension.js

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
// When DOM is loaded
Text.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    console.log('new message');
};
```

> index.html

```
<!-- language: lang-html-->
// When DOM is loaded
editor = new Editor();
editor.init();
```

Comment: How is `extension.js` loaded?

Comment: seconding @aug, if I put this in a pen and run it sequentially it says 'new message' (https://codepen.io/abrady0/pen/VrKKBP?editors=1111)

Comment: @noob the code works fine even if keeping the file structure same as yours. It always shows `new message` in `console`. Loading sequence in index file is `<script src="editor.js"></script>` followed by `<script src="extension.js"></script>` and finally `editor.init()` codes.

Comment: @aug, the `extension.js` loaded after the `editor.js`. Thanks guys I will keep going.